# Counting identical list-elements in a row in Python

Tags: python, list

I am using Python3. I have a list `a` of only integers. Now, I want to save the element and the number it repeats itself in a row in another list.

Example:

```
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
```

> Output:

```
result = ["6,1", "0, 2", "2, 4", "1, 1", "89, 2"]    
# the number before the "," represents the element, the number after the "," represents how many times it repeats itself.
```

How to efficiently achieve my goal ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I count the occurrences of a list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item)

Answer (score 3):

I believe all the solutions given are counting the total occurrences of a number in the list rather than counting the repeating runs of a number.

Here is a solution using groupby from itertools. It gathers the runs and appends them to a dictionary keyed by the number.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
d = dict()

for k, v in groupby(a):
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(len(list(v)))
```

Dictionary created:

```
>>> d
{6: [1], 0: [2], 2: [4], 1: [1], 89: [2]}
```

Note that all runs only had 1 count in their list. If there where other occurrences of a number already seen, there would be multiple counts in the lists (that are the values for dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

for counting an individual element,
us `list.count`,

i.e, here, for, say `2`, we user
`a.count(2)`,
which outputs `4`,

also,
`set(a)` gives the unique elements in `a`

overall answer,

```
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
nums = set(a)
result = [f"{val}, {a.count(val)}" for val in set(a)]
print(result)
```

which gives

```
['0, 2', '1, 1', '2, 4', '6, 1', '89, 2']
```

Comment: Is this method O(n) = n*n?

Comment: set(a) is O(n) (worst case), calculating result is O(n), I think it should be, O(n) + O(n), i.e. O(n) (I think, I'm to very good at this)

Comment: and a.count(val) inside the for doesn't it make O(n*n)?

Answer (score 1):

> **Method 1:** using *for loop*

```
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
result = []
a_set = set(a) # transform the list into a set to have unique integer
for nbr in a_set:
    nbr_count = a.count(nbr)
    result.append("{},{}".format(nbr, nbr_count))

print(result) # ['0,2', '1,1', '2,4', '6,1', '89,2']
```

> **Method 2:** using *list-comprehensions*

```
result = ["{},{}".format(item, a.count(item)) for item in set(a)]
print(result) # ['0,2', '1,1', '2,4', '6,1', '89,2']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Python List `count()` Method, method returns the number of elements with the specified value.

```
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]

print ({x:a.count(x) for x in a})
```

output:

```
{6: 1, 0: 2, 2: 4, 1: 1, 89: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
dic = dict()
for i in a:
     if(i in dic):
             dic[i] = dic[i] + 1
     else:
             dic[i] = 1

result = []
for i in dic:
     result.append(str(i) +"," + str(dic[i]))
```

Or:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
mylist = [Counter(a)]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from collections:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [6, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 89, 89]
counter = Counter(a)    
result = ['{},{}'.format(k, v) for k,v in counter.items()]
```